# Visual Studio 2013 doesn't respond after updating the WCF service references from Front End project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Whenever I update WCF service reference in front end project, the service reference update happens and the bottom left corner of Visual Studio indicates that the service reference update is complete, but Visual Studio becomes non responsive after the update. If I close the Visual studio using the Task manager and restart it, reopen the solution, I can proceed as normal and can use the updated service reference. For now I always restart my Visual studio and reopen my solution to continue working on my tasks. Has anyone faced this issue? If anyone found the solution for this issue, could you please help me fixing this as it is very annoying to restart the Visual studio every time I update the service references. Thank you.

(I am using Visual Studio 2013 - project uses .Net Framework, asp.net webforms, and C# as the language for development. - if it helps.)

Answer (score 0):

After trying different options, I guess the size of sln file and the size of references caused the issue for me. We use Resharper in our company which adds extra load when updating the service references.

My Visual Studio doesn't hang/becomes not responsive (most of the times), when i do the following..
1) Go to Tools -> Options -> Source Control - change the default option from Microsoft Git Provider to None.
2) Tools -> Options -> Resharper Ultimate  and disabl it.
3) Try to figure out which projects in the solution is not required or affected and unload them.

Then update the reference. Still sometimes it doesn't work for me, but most of the times i dont have to restart the solution using task manager. I always disable resharper before I have to update the service reference and enable it back again once the service reference is updated. Hope it help others if they face similar situations..